# Quickblox chat setting save_to_history to true in Xamarin C# SDK

Tags: c#, xamarin, sdk, quickblox

I'm using [Quickblox C# SDK](http://quickblox.com/developers/Xamarin). I want to send message to a specific dialog. It's not well documented in Xamarin specific documentation. I decided to visit [REST API documentation](http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Server-side_chat_history). As I could learn from there

> By using Chat 2.0, you are not automatically storing your messages. Also a dialog entity won't be created/updated without saving a message to history.

I can infer if I set `save_to_history` to 1, chat dialog will be automatically created and message will be stored in the backend. However I couldn't figure out how I should specify that in C# SDK, cause `extraParam` in this method signature

```
public void SendMessage(int userId, string body, string extraParams, string dialogId, string subject = null, Quickblox.Sdk.Modules.ChatXmppModule.Models.MessageType messageType = Quickblox.Sdk.Modules.ChatXmppModule.Models.MessageType.Chat)
```

is just a string. I've dug into disassembled code and after some investigation understood that internally this parameter is used as XML so I tried these two options

```
var extraParams = "<extraParams> " +
                      "<save_to_history>1</save_to_history> " +
                  "</extraParams>";
```

And Also

```
var extraParams = "<save_to_history>1</save_to_history> ";
```

But none of these worked.
Anybody has idea how I should specify the extraParam?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was simply that I forgot to call connect before I was sending a message. 
Here is the method to send a message

```
public async Task SendMessageAsync(IUser sender, IChatMessage message, string channelID, CancellationToken token)
    {
        await loginIfRequired(sender, token);
        var jsonMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
        var recipientID = await getQuickbloxUserId(message.RecipientID, token);
        var extraParams = "<extraParams> " +
                            "<save_to_history>1</save_to_history> " +
                          "</extraParams>";
        _quickblox.ChatXmppClient.SendMessage(recipientID, jsonMessage, extraParams, channelID);
    }
```

Inside `loginIfRequired` I call

```
_quickblox.ChatXmppClient.Connect(_currentUserID.Value, password);
```

And everything worked fine and the dialog was created.
Hope this will help someone.